# How to fill a data range fast in Excel?

Tags: arrays, excel, series

Is there a way in Excel (I have Ms Office 365) - to copy or to fill series of numbers automatically, with one of few mouse clicks or keyboard entrees ?
For example - I need to quickly fill number 1 to 100 000 or to 1 000 000 in my excel, without dragging mouse all the way down...

Thank you for any advice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula to create a sequence of one million integers

```
=SEQUENCE(1000000)
```

Copy then Paste Special>Values if you don't want to retain it as a dynamic array formula.

Comment: That you!  Perfect (I knew "paste special") but didn't know about Sequence()

Answer (score 0):

Enter 1 into A1,
enter =A1+1 into A2,
copy A2,
go to A1000000,
press Ctrl + Shift + Up,
paste.

Modify according to your exact needs.

Comment: It'll take time to "go" to A1000000, Are there any quick way to go to that?
Or if I need to go to the very last excel row (A1048576)?

Comment: @Hell-1931 Yes, there's the box in top left corner showing your current cell address – you can type A1000000 in there and press enter.